# Select elements with multiple classes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If an element has multiple classes like this:

```
class="btn btn-primary add-movie-button is-on"
```

can I select it only by one class name using jQuery like:

```
$(".add-movie-button")
```

Can I use `.hasClass("is-on")` for this element?

Comment: Yes? Why do you ask? Did you try and it didn't work?

Comment: `$(".add-movie-button.is-on.btn")` should work

Comment: @j08691: Are you sure about that duplicate? This seems to ask if a single class can be used even though the element has multiple.

Comment: @squint fair enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a class on an element like so: `class="btn btn-primary add-movie-button is-on"`

You can select by one or more than one class.  Adding more classes increases specificity.

For example:

```
$(".add-movie-button")
```

is less specific than

```
$(".add-movie-button.is-on")
```

In either case you can use the hasClass returning a boolean;

```
var isClassy = $(".add-movie-button.is-on").hasClass("is-on");
var isSmallClassy = $(".add-movie-button").hasClass("is-on");
```

Note that this would return true if ANY element matched the conditions.  If you desire to see if ALL do then use length:

```
var longClasses = $(".add-movie-button.is-on");
var shortClasses = $(".add-movie-button");

var both = longClasses.length === shortClasses.length;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Can I use .hasClass("is-on") for this element?**
The Answer is yes!

```
if($(".add-movie-button").hasClass("is-on")){
  console.log('it worked')
}
```